# Is there a way to handle NAs when coming up with a sum?

Tags: r, na

Sorry in advance if I don't format this question great, it's my first time posting a question!

I have a table with patients as rows and symptoms as columns. Symptom response is 0/1 (absent/present). I am noticing 3 different ways data has been entered. (1) All data is available (patient A), (2) All data is missing (patient D), OR only some columns are missing data and other columns have a response (patients B, C, or E).

```
> patient<- c('A','B','C','D', 'E')
> symptom1<- c(1,0,1,NA,1)
> symptom2<- c(0,NA,NA,NA,0)
> symptom3<- c(0,NA,NA,NA,NA)
> df<- data.frame(patient, symptom1, symptom2, symptom3)
> df
  patient symptom1 symptom2 symptom3
1       A        1        0        0
2       B        0       NA       NA
3       C        1       NA       NA
4       D       NA       NA       NA
5       E        1        0       NA
```

I want to create a new column, 'disease' with response 0/1 so that if the patient has any 1s, then disease==1, but they must have all 0s for disease==0. Essentially, I want to ignore all the NAs when there are values present in the row, but if a row is entirely NAs, I want disease==NA.

I have tried using na.rm=TRUE but as you can see in patient D, it is treating NAs like 0:

```
> df$disease<- apply(df[2:4], 1, sum, na.rm=TRUE)
> df
  patient symptom1 symptom2 symptom3 disease
1       A        1        0        0       1
2       B        0       NA       NA       0
3       C        1       NA       NA       1
4       D       NA       NA       NA       0
5       E        1        0       NA       1
```

This is a problem because if all columns are NA, we don't actually have enough information to say that the patient is not experiencing any symptoms- maybe they are just missing data. Any experience/suggestions for handling NAs in a situation like this?

Comment: `apply(df[2:4], 1, function(x) sum(x, na.rm = !all(is.na(x))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is `sum_` from `hablar`

```
library(hablar)
df$disease <- apply(df[2:4], 1, sum_)
df$disease
#[1]  1  0  1 NA  1
```

---

Or using the OP's approach, we can have a `if/else` condition

```
apply(df[2:4], 1, function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_real_
          else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))
#[1]  1  0  1 NA  1
```

---

Or another vectorized option is

```
rowSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE) * NA^!rowSums(!is.na(df[-1]))
#[1]  1  0  1 NA  1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Literally the first suggestion worked perfectly. Didn't know about that package.